# Rebuild thumbnails via WP Cli - how?

Tags: images, media-library, thumbnails, wp-cli

I can use `wp media regenerate` to regenerate thumbnails. But I need to rebuild first, before I can regenerate.

In the GUI of WordPress I have two buttons (if I have AJAX Regenerate Thumbnails plugin):

[image]

I need to click "Rebuild Thumbnails" and then "Regenerate Thumbnails" before my problem is fixed - I need to do this on thousands of images; is there an easy way to do this via the CLI?

Comment: What specifically does rebuild do?

Comment: It looks like Rebuild Thumbnails in that plugin just allows you to select which image sizes you want to regenerate. So, no, it cannot be done via the CLI.